# React calling function?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, list, visual-studio

Slightly new to react and playing around with lists, not sure why my code isn't performing as required, when I call the method it just displays plain html

Ive tried putting it between  tags but nothing

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import List from './List'

class App extends Component { //different
  render() { //different
    // The rest of the file is the same
    return(
    <div className="App"> 
    Liste();

    </div>)
  };


}

function Liste(){
  const names=['d','d']

  return(<div>
  <h2>{names[0]}</h2>
   <h2> {names[1]}</h2>
  </div>)
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Liste` function is a functional component so it needs to be included like any other react component and not to be executed as a function. Just replace your return statement in your App component to

```
return(
    <div className="App"> 
      <Liste />;
    </div>)
  };
```

You can go through this link to learn the syntax - https://devhints.io/react

Comment: How would I do the same thing if Liste has two parameters?

Comment: If you want to pass two parameters to `Liste` then do <Liste param1="abc" param2="fsd"/> and use in `Liste` as props. Do go through the react docs for all usecases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
const Liste = () => {
  const names=['d','d']

  return(
     <div>
        <h2>{names[0]}</h2>
        <h2> {names[1]}</h2>
     </div>
   );
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <div className="App"> 
          <Liste />
        </div>
    );
  };
}

export default App;
```

Comment: works aswell but I saw his aripithas reply first, thank you so much though

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
class App extends Component { //different
  render() { //different
    // The rest of the file is the same
    return(
    <div className="App"> 
    {Liste()}

    </div>)
  };


}

function Liste(){
  const names=['d','d']

  return(<div>
  <h2>{names[0]}</h2>
   <h2> {names[1]}</h2>
  </div>)
}

export default App;
```